# Append value/index for each duplicated row within a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a sorted Dataframe with some duplicated ids and I wanted to make the ids unique by appending the index in which they appear in their duplicated list.

Original df:

```
id val
1  100
1  526
2  434
3  234 
4  657
4  44
4  121
```

Notice how there are duplicate `ids`.

This is what I'm hoping for:

```
id val
1  100
1-1  526
2  434
3  234 
4  657
4-1  44
4-2  121
```

Would also be ok with:

```
id val
1-0  100
1-1  526
2-0  434
3-0  234 
4-0  657
4-1  44
4-2  121
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['id'] = df['id'].astype(str) + '-' + df.groupby('id').cumcount().astype(str)

    id  val
0  1-0  100
1  1-1  526
2  2-0  434
3  3-0  234
4  4-0  657
5  4-1   44
6  4-2  121
```

Comment: Ahh this did it. I was messing with .duplicated for a while but this is great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
df['id'] = df.groupby('id')['id'].transform(lambda x: ['{}-{}'.format(v, i) if i else v for i, v in enumerate(x)])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    id  val
0    1  100
1  1-1  526
2    2  434
3    3  234
4    4  657
5  4-1   44
6  4-2  121
```